# Is $y=\frac{x^2}{x^3+3}$ has a horizontal asymptote?

Tags: graphing-functions, rational-functions

Is $y=\frac{x^2}{x^3+3}$ has a horizontal asymptote?

Since the graph passes through $(0,0)$, hence $y=0$ is not a horizontal asymptote. Can a rational function may not have a horizontal asymptote?

Comment: It is perfectly possible for a rational function not to have a horizontal asymptote. Consider $f(x)=x+1/x$ as an example. But, why does $(0,0)$ being on the graph make it impossible for $y=0$ to be an asymptote? Whether something is an asymptote or not is decided far away from the origin (either in the $x$ or $y$ direction or somewhere in-between). Anything that happens "before we approach infinity" is irrelevant.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

An *asymptote* is a straight line to which the curve approaches while it moves away from the origin. The curve can approach the line from one side, or it can intersect it again and again. Not every curve which goes infinitely far from the origin (infinite branch of the curve) has an asymptote.

For functions given in explicit form  $y=f(x)$,  we know: the vertical asymptotes are at points of discontinuity where the function  $f(x)$  has an infinite jump; the horizontal and oblique asymptotes have the equation:

$$y=kx+b, \space \text{ with } \space \space k=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}, \space \space b=\lim_{x \to \infty}\left[f(x)-kx \right].$$

**Figure**:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Yes, of course:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^3+3}=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{1+\frac{3}{x^3}}=0,$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^3+3}=\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{1+\frac{3}{x^3}}=0.$$
Id est, $y=0$ is a horizontal asymptote.

The function $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{x^2+3}$ has no a horizontal asymptote.

Comment: May I enquire as to why your first reaction is NOT to look for an earlier question where this confusion is explained? Not that you actually addressed the confusion at all.